# selecting an element within other div

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's look at first the codes bolow

```
<div class="div1">
   <p>Hello There</p>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
   <p>Hello There</p>
</div>
```

I want to select `<p>` in the `div-main` by `div1`.suppose i have `div2` instead of `div1`.In that case how i can select `<p>` of a `div-main`

I tried :

```
div1+div-main p{}
```

But it should not work.Is there any working functions there?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.div-main > p {...}` to select the `p` tag inside the `.div-main` element

But if you only want to select those directly following a `.div1` element (?), use this:

```css
.div1+.div-main p { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   <p>Hello There</p>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
   <p>Hello There</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.div1` to target the class `div1`

use `~` to find next `.div-main` class

use `>` to target child `p`

```css
.div1 ~ .div-main > p{
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   <p>Hello There 1</p>
</div>
<div class="div2">
   <p>Hello There 2</p>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
   <p>Hello There Main</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the class selector must be preceeded from a dot ".div-main" and ".div1". The code:

```css
.div1+.div-main p {
  color:red;
}

.div2+.div-main p {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
   <p>next red</p>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
   <p>Hello There</p>
</div>

<div class="div2">
   <p>next green</p>
</div>
<div class="div-main">
   <p>Hello There</p>
</div>

<div class="div-main">
   <p>Green ? no!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
    <body>  
   <div class="div1">
       <p>Hello There</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div-main">
       <p>Hello There</p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

**CSS**

```
    <style>
    .div-main p {
        color:Blue;
    }
    </style>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FEVSB2EMHKLD